# With webform_civicrm, how to add contact2's lineitem info into Registration Confirmation and Receipt template

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, drupal-7

I have set up a civievent with a webform_civicrm booking form, where the employer is contact1 and the individual delegate is contact 2.

The main event uses the event participation field, and additional options are set up with lineitem fields.

is there a way to add contact2's participation and lineitem info into the Registration Confirmation and Receipt template?

(Site uses pp to date D7 and Civi)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to send two receipts out for this ->

1. one confirmation email triggered from webform: you have all webform submitted values available as tokens to compose an very email with perhaps including maps/directions, speaker bio, anything really.
2. one (boring) transaction receipt email triggered from civicrm: it only serves as a payment confirmation receipt.

Comment: Thanks Karin - Is your approach because its not possible to add contact2's booking info to the template, or because you can do nicer comms through webform? 
And do you edit the default Registration Confirmation and Receipt template at all?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the default template in CiviCRM but it is used for all events so you need to “if smarty” a lot and it’s raw HTML. I really like the nicer comms - get the WYSIWYG editor for webform as well.